# Как добавить скрытый слой в pytorch resnet18?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Пробую учить машинное обучение. Нашёл нейросетку, которая смотрит фотографии и выводит фейки. Но не устраивает точность нейронки. Знаю, что если добавить скрытые слои, то можно повысить её точность. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: поделитесь информацией - откуда такая уверенность, что дополнительные скрытые слои повысят точность НС? ;)

Comment: @MaxU, ну может у него ни одного скрытого слоя нет?)))

Comment: @Qwertiy жестко вы так))

Comment: @MaxU, да прочитал где-то... Я совсем ещё зелёный в этом деле, потому, возможно, и задал глупый вопрос

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, врядли у модели `pytorch`, которая(на сколько я понял) уже настроена именно на работу с картинками и тп, не будет ни одного скрытого слоя